# Custom form field type embedded form Symfony2

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I have three entities:

- Diet, Menu and Meal
- Diet has one collection of Menus,
- Menu has one collectiion of Meals.

So I have to create an embedded form for Diet.

I follow the documentation of embedded form of Symfony2, but that is not so simple.

Ok. What I need first:

- Each form of Diet needs to have two Menus.
- Each form of Menus needs to have three Meals. (I don't know if it's possible).

I can do this in controller and send to twig. But the problem is when I 'allow_add',
to dynamicaly add forms.

That is the problem:

[image]

The code:

```
class DietType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('calories')
            ->add('menus', 'collection', array('type' => new MenuType(),
            'allow_add' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'prototype' => true   
        ));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Project\FoodBundle\Entity\Diet',
            );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'diet';
    }
}

class MenuType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('description')
            ->add('meals', 'collection', array('type' => new MealType(),
                           'allow_add' => true, 'by_reference' => false,
                           'prototype' => true
                 ));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Project\FoodBundle\Entity\Menu',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'menu';
    }
}

class MealType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Project\FoodBundle\Entity\Meal',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'meal';
    }
}
```

And the Twig template:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

<h1>Diet creation</h1>

<form action="{{ path('diet_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>

    {{ form_row(form.calories) }}

        <div id = "menus" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.menus.vars.prototype)|e }}">

        <h3>Menus</h3>
        {% for menu in form.menus %}
        <ul class="menu">
               {{ _self.prototype(menu)  }}
        </ul>
        {% endfor %}

        {% macro prototype(menu) %}
        {{ form_row(menu.description) }}
        <li class="meal">
            {% for meal in menu.meals %}
                {{ form_row(meal.name) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
        {% endmacro %}
    </div>

    <p>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </p>
</form>

<script>

var collectionHolder = $('#menus');

var $addMenuLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_menu_link">Add menu</a>');
var $newLinkMenuLi = $('<li></li>').append($addMenuLink);

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#menus').append($newLinkMenuLi);

    $.each($('ul.menu'), function(){
        $(this).append('<a href="#"> Add meal </a>');
    });

    $addMenuLink.click( function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a new menu form (see next code block)
        addMenuForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkMenuLi);
    });

    function addMenuForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkMenuLi){
        // Get the data-prototype we explained earlier
        var prototype = collectionHolder.attr('data-prototype');

        // Replace '$$name$$' in the prototype's HTML to
        // instead be a number based on the current collection's length.
        var newForm = prototype.replace(/\$\$name\$\$/g, collectionHolder.children().length);

        // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a menu" link li
        var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
        $newLinkMenuLi.before($newFormLi);
    }


});

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the validation, try adding a [validator callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) on your Diet and Menu entities and it should be OK :)

Now for the form theme, you can take a look at the [form theming documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GeoffreyBrier. But it's not what I'm trying to do =/

Comment: Sorry,well i never tried to 'inception' collection of collection of forms. Can't you simply divide it into 3 parts? One to create diets, the second one for the Diet => Menu collection (add multiple menu for a specific diet) and the last one for the Menu => Meal collection (add multiple meals for a specific menu). I think it would definitely be faster to implement.

Comment: The previous version of the program makes it. In this update we are trying to add new dinamic methods to the program. Thanks anyway.